# How to divide two strings in Java, if ValueOF or Integer.parseInt are not working?

Tags: java, string, selenium, oop, automation

i must divide the results of two strings in Java. I hava tried valueOF, parseUnsignedInt and other methods, but the problem is, that for the first string they does not work. The strings are `getText()` results from a certain web element, which i am getting using `Selenium`. Here is my code

```
System.out.println( Integer.valueOf(st) /Integer.parseUnsignedInt( element.getAttribute("innerHTML").substring(16) ));
```

Here is error which i have

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10,768"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

`10768` is the string number for my `String st`
How can I handle this situation to get the division number correctly?

Comment: Try it without the comma, just `10768`.

Comment: I am getting the number from a web element, so I can't change the comma

Comment: Then use a *regex* to replace that comma with a *blank* space before parsing it. You can't convert a `,` to an `int`

Comment: You can do this creating a DecimalFormat

Comment: I believe you should be more concrete - your input string looks like double value. What your expectation of parsing: ```10,768d``` : ```10``` :```11```:```10768```

Comment: Maybe of low reliabilty, but you could do `int num = Integer.parseInt(st.replace(",", ""));` to have the number without a comma. This may lead to problems in some situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the String value containing the comma into an integer using:

```
int value = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse(element.getAttribute("innerHTML").substring(16));
```

And then you can use this value for your division like:

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(st)/value);
```